# How to reliably identify device on web service?

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, cryptography, tpm

Scenario :

- The desktop computer is being authenticated on web service
- I provide the .exe on the desktop
- I control the web service
- The desktop has a TPM chip installed

Is this reliable method :

On https connection :

- Alice requests random number from Bob in publicly accessible web service
- Alice signs random number with her private key within TPM 2.0
- Alice sends signed random number to Bob
- Bob verifies that Alice signed random number

Comment: This would allow Alice to verify that Bob has (access to) a machine with a TPM, however, it does not block any tamper (a.k.a modification) of the .exe file since only the number and not the .exe is signed by the TPM.

Comment: I know that. In this step I'm only verifying identity of device (from which request was send). Is there a more common and simpler method?

Comment: That highly depends on your threat model. If you assume that the adversary wouldn't copy a file from computer to another, simply generating a private key once on the client side and using it to authenticate itself would be enough. Using a TPM as a key storage also has limitations. One could, for example, desolder a TPM module from one mainboard and solder it onto another or attack the TPM directly, which has already been done in the past. (There are even DefCon talks on attacking TPM's)